# Poltly Express `scatter_mapbox` with `animation_frame` and `color`

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

If have data with columns : 'e_lat', 'e_lon', 'Année' and 'Expéditeur'.
**I'm trying to make a scatter_mapbox, with frames animated by 'Année", and color based on 'Expéditeur' (which is categorical, the names of the persons).**

```py
# I created a row df['_color'] = df['Expéditeur'] because in the end I want to change the way _color is defined.

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        lat='e_lat',
                        lon='e_lon',
                        hover_name='Ville Expéditeur',
                        hover_data=['Expéditeur', 'Destinataire', 'Ville Expéditeur', 'Année'],
                        animation_frame='Année',
                        mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                        zoom=4,
                        color='_color',
                        )
fig.show()
```

The trouble is I get something like this :
(only the points that have the first color are showing)
[image: Animation frame ok but missing some points.]

If I comment out `color='_color',`, I get :
[image: Animation frame ok but no color of course.]
If I comment out `animation_frame='Année'',`, I get :
[image: Color are ok but no animation frames of course.]

I did a lot of research but it always seems to me that people are doing exactly the same and have different results ([this tutorial for example](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-animate-scatterplots-on-mapbox-using-plotly-express-3bb49fe6a5d, [this stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527823/plotly-express-plot-scatter-mapbox-with-feature-colors-from-dataframe-column-p), ...)

My plotly lib is up-to-date.

I tried a lot of different things with `animation group, color_discrete_map, color_discrete_sequence etc. but without any success).

What am I doing wrong here ? Thx a lot.

---

[EDIT]
In fact it's exaclty the same problem than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61697962/plotly-express-seemingly-only-taking-color-attributes-from-first-frame-of-animat) (not resolved).
This seems to be because of a [documented bug of Plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2259).
"If all colors are used for the first frame, the problem disappears."

I solved it by adding "fake data" (outside of the scope of the map) : one for each color, in the first frame of the animation.

```py
new_rows = []
for color in df['_color'].unique():
    new_row = {'_color': color, 'Année': df['Année'].min(), 'lat': 0, 'lon': 0}
    new_rows.append(new_row)
df = df.append(new_rows, ignore_index=True)
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I have a workaround by using density_mapbox. There is a bug in scatter_mapbox where I think canvas plots aren't refreshed on animation frame change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact it's exaclty the same problem than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61697962/plotly-express-seemingly-only-taking-color-attributes-from-first-frame-of-animat) (not resolved).
This seems to be because of a [documented bug of Plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2259).
"If all colors are used for the first frame, the problem disappears."

I solved it by adding "fake data" (outside of the scope of the map) : one for each color, in the first frame of the animation.

```py
new_rows = []
for color in df['_color'].unique():
    new_row = {'_color': color, 'Année': df['Année'].min(), 'lat': 0, 'lon': 0}
    new_rows.append(new_row)
df = df.append(new_rows, ignore_index=True)
```

Hope this will help someone.